# Automatic saving of LogCat to a file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logcat

Like in putty where you can configure to save putty sessions to a log file, is there any option in eclipse where I can configure to save all logcat messages to a log file automatically?  I woldn't mind installing a plugin which could help me achieve the same.

I am aware of manually selecting and saving option but this is not something i want.